# Php image resize only width, auto-adjusting the height

Tags: php, image, resize

There is a system that reshapes images with php. I set the width value. I want it to get the height value automatically. In its current form, there is white space on the right side of some images. how can i lose this space. I want the height value to be scaled automatically.

[image]

```
public function resize(int $width = 0, int $height = 0, $default = '') {
    if (!$this->width || !$this->height) {
        return;
    }

    $xpos = 0;
    $ypos = 0;
    $scale = 1;

    $scale_w = $width / $this->width;
    $scale_h = 1;

    if ($default == 'w') {
        $scale = $scale_w;
    } elseif ($default == 'h') {
        $scale = $scale_h;
    } else {
        $scale = min($scale_w, $scale_h);
    }

    if ($scale == 1 && $scale_h == $scale_w && ($this->mime != 'image/png' && $this->mime != 'image/webp')) {
        return;
    }

    $new_width = (int)($this->width * $scale);
    $new_height = (int)($this->height * $scale);
    $xpos = 0;
    $ypos = 0;

    $image_old = $this->image;
    $this->image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $new_height);

    if ($this->mime == 'image/png') {
        imagealphablending($this->image, false);
        imagesavealpha($this->image, true);

        $background = imagecolorallocatealpha($this->image, 255, 255, 255, 127);

        imagecolortransparent($this->image, $background);

    } else if ($this->mime == 'image/webp') {
        imagealphablending($this->image, false);
        imagesavealpha($this->image, true);

        $background = imagecolorallocatealpha($this->image, 255, 255, 255, 127);

        imagecolortransparent($this->image, $background);
    } else {
        $background = imagecolorallocate($this->image, 255, 255, 255);
    }

    imagefilledrectangle($this->image, 0, 0, $width, $new_height, $background);

    imagecopyresampled($this->image, $image_old, $xpos, $ypos, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $this->width, $this->height);
    imagedestroy($image_old);

    $this->width = $width;
    $this->height = $new_height;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely missing the `$default` parameter, it should be `'w'`.

**As an example:**

Let's say you have an image 128 x 128 and want to resize it to 256 (width), it should be scaled up to 256 x 256. The call looks like:

See how the resize scale is calculated:

```php
$scale_w = $width / $this->width; // 256 / 128 = 2
$scale_h = 1;

if ($default == 'w') {
    $scale = $scale_w; // = 2
} elseif ($default == 'h') {
    $scale = $scale_h; // = 1
} else {
    $scale = min($scale_w, $scale_h); // = 1
}
```

Without `'w'` flag `$scale` becomes `1` and with `'w'` flag it becomes `2` - the expected value.

Later on the algorithm uses `$width` several times instead of `$new_width` so the new image will be 256w x 128h instead of 128 x 128 due this line:

```php
$this->image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $new_height);
```

But `imagecopyresampled` uses `$new_width` so you end up with an 256w x 128h image, containing the original 128 x 128 image.